# Python - How can I create multiple folders in a newly created directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm very new to this, Im essentially trying to create a script for working on feature films so that everyday I can have a new set of folders made for that specific shoot day that I can the offload files too.

So far I have been able to have a Folder made with the users input of which shoot day they are on and then add the actual date to that file name.

But where I am stuck is trying to add folders within this newly created folder.

```
print ('')
print '\033[4m' + "Hello, Please select a shoot day to begin - this only works up until 12pm" + '\033[0m'
import os
import sys
import time, datetime

today = datetime.date.today()  # get today's date as a datetime type

todaystr = today.isoformat()   # get string representation: YYYY_MM_DD
                               # from a datetime type.


print('')
user_input = raw_input('\033[1m' + 'Enter Shoot Day Here -' + '\033[0m')

path1 = user_input
if not os.path.exists(path1):
    os.makedirs(path1 +'_' + todaystr)
```

So this created me a folder called 015_2016-12-24. I then want to be able to add several folders with folders inside of these folders.

Just trying my best here sorry if this is a dumb question.  Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 4):

```
os.makedirs(path1 +'_' + todaystr+'/'+name of subfolder)
```

this will allow you to create subfolder for your newly created folder

Comment: Okay perfect, I knew it would be something simple. 

But then how would I go about adding more than one folder at a time ?

Lets says I wanted to create 3 folders called 'ari' 'sound' and 'md5' and wanted them to all be in that top folder? Simply adding - 

`os.makedirs(path1 +'_' + todaystr+'/ari'+'sound')` 

Would just made the folder name 'arisound" right ?

Comment: @JonathanPetts `for name in ['ari' , 'sound', 'md5']: os.makedirs(path1 +'_' + todaystr + name)`. This will create three subfolders.